# Is it possible to "force stop" an application I am debugging using adb in terminal?

Tags: android, command-line, adb

I am developing an app, and for debugging certain actions on first installation I found that using the terminal command:

```
./adb uninstall <package-name>
```

was a lot fast than navigating to settings, apps, waiting for the apps to load, finding your app, and uninstalling it. I would strongly recommend it for anyone that doesn't already use it for debugging.

Now I am trying to work on the force close part of my app, and I can't find anywhere in the android doc, instructions on how to force close an app by adb command.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can close one by his pid using

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

but I'm not sure of doing it with a package name.

Comment: You can first issue: "adb shell ps".
Parse the result and find the PID.

Answer (score 22):

```
am force-stop YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME
```

This command worked for me. Hope so this will help you as well.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `adb shell kill` to kill the process, but first you need to find the process id. To do this you can use `adb shell ps` and parse the output. Here is a sample (assuming your development PC is Unix):

```
adb shell kill $(adb shell ps | grep YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: This is an awesome command. But I get 
'could not kill pid 6551: Operation not permitted'
 does the phone need to be rooted?

Comment: @BerniePerez the answer to your question is "yes", by the way. Great answer!

Comment: Operation not permitted fix: `adb shell "su -c 'kill $(adb shell ps | grep YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME | awk '{ print $2 }')'"`

Comment: You need a root device to kill

Answer (score 3):

```
adb killall YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME
```

I've created a batch script to run this command.

Comment: Has to be `adb shell`, `su`, then `killall YOU.PACKAGE.NAME` for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `awk` for some reason (incomplete cygwin installation in my case), the following might work:

`adb shell ps | grep YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME |  sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | adb shell kill`

Explanation: First, `ps` lists running processes. From the output, `grep` gets the line containing YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME. `sed` truncates consecutive spaces into one to help `cut` can get the package name part of that line. Finally, the process id is piped to `kill`.

Comment: You need to have sed (I have it only when I install `busybox`).