# Stopping Robotium test execution

Tags: android, jenkins, automated-tests, robotium

I have a Jenkins job that starts a Robotium test from command line:

> adb shell am instrument -w com.foo.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Sometimes the test run gets stuck. When I abort the Jenkins job, it does not stop the Robotium test run. I may have to cancel the test execution manually from the device before running another Jenkins job.

How do I stop the test execution? I cannot just uninstall the application under test with `adb uninstall` since it has active device admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cancel the previous Robotium test by starting another test one with a made-up test name:

> adb shell am instrument -e class com.foo.tests#dummyTestName com.foo.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>
```

Comment: At least on my Galaxy S (OS 2.3.3) it is not available (yet). I get `Error: Unknown command: force-stop`. Maybe it is available on later OS versions, maybe in Honeycomb (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11511123/1097104).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the app data,like this

```
adb shell pm clear com.foo.tests
```

Comment: This does not seem to stop the execution, at least not on Galaxy S (OS 2.3.3).